# How to compute the pullback of $\left( x_4- x_2 x_4\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_1}+\left( x_4+x_5\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_2}+....$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I'm trying to do a pullback of a differential form.

Where
 $\omega=\left( x_4- x_2 x_4\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_1}+\left( x_4+x_5\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_2}+\left( x_5-x_2\text{  }x_5\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_3}-\left(x_2\text{
 }x_5-x_1 x_3\text{  }x_5\right)\frac{d}{\text{dx}_4}+x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 \frac{d}{\text{dx}_5}$

is a differential form on $\mathbb{R}^{5}$

since $f : \mathbb{R}^{5} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$f=x_1 x_4+x_2 x_4-x_1 x_2 x_4+x_2 x_5+x_3 x_5-x_2 x_3 x_5-x_2 x_4 x_5-x_1 x_3 x_4 x_5+x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5$$

How I can calculate the pullback. I was try to do a pullback by definition.But I did not get a result because it is general in $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ and I am starting on this subject

How I take a general vector and calculate the form?

Can this be done?
Can an assistant find a solution or mention the steps

Please help and thank you anyway

Comment: A pullback by ... what map?

Comment: @Bye_World see new update

Comment: OK.  Two more issues. (1) You've defined $\omega$ as a vector, not a differential form and (2) if I were to just mentally convert the $\frac{d}{dx_i}$'s to $dx_i$'s, you'd still need the codomain of $f$ to be $\Bbb R^5$.  As of right now $\omega$ and $f$ are incompatible.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576638/how-to-calculate-the-pullback-of-a-k-form-explicitly) an example of how to perform a pullback on a differential form.