# calculate $\Phi^{*}\omega \;$ for a given $\omega$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

so 
we have :

$$\Phi : \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$

$$(x,y,z) \mapsto (xy,yz^2,z^3)$$

How can I calculate $\Phi^{*}\omega \; $   for :

i) $\omega= x\,dx\wedge dz - dx\wedge dy$

ii) $\omega= x\,dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$

Any help would be appreciate thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need help with? It is a direct calculation.

Comment: I don't know the formula , that's why I'm asking if you can do it for just one of them just to have an idea , thanks.

Comment: A very similar calculation is performed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/576679/629362). (And it is better to state in the question that you don't know the formula, so that others at least know where to start).

Comment: Ok , I'll check. (You're right , i saw a lot of step by step answers i thought I'd get one.)